# Visual Studio Team Services - secure access to office environment only

Tags: security, tfs, azure-devops

We use Visual Studio Team Services to manage our sourcecode and scrum.
We have 2 developers working at 2 separate offices.

I do not want developers logging in at home and grabbing code for their own use.

How can i lock down the access to Visual Studio Team Services from only the offices PCs?

Comment: You may get better response over at the [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Comment: @zcleghern that seems unlikely. looking at their site, it doesn't seem like this would be on-topic there.

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Yes, sorry i mean VS online.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control access from location, only by account.

To be honest its not a good question.

--If you don't trust your developers then why did you hire then?

--Why can't they plug a USB stick into their office computer and copy the code?

--Cant they email the code to themselves?

You are in a losing battle. If you don't trust the people that work for you then you have hired the wrong people. Fire them and get people that you can trust.

Comment: Thank for the response but sorry,  i disagree, by the same argument should we give all employees the office key and alarm code? We trust them right?
The truth is companies need to lock down access correctly. If this is not easily achievable via VS online then we will need to stick to TFS in-house on our internal network.

Comment: And you can lock down access. You can give a developer access only to the artifacts that he needs.

Comment: Actually it is a good question.  It would be a really good feature to be able to configure a VSO instance to only allow access from certain IP ranges.  We have GPO policies in place that disable removable media.

Comment: "I don't trust my developers, how do i" is never the start of a good question. If you want a new feature you can request it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com